# How to include dependent projects XML-comment files during a publish?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, publish, xml-comments

When I use the "normal" "Publish-tool" built into Visual Studio for ASP.net, it seems like it does not include XML-comment-files that belongs to dependent projects/assemblies.

For instance, lets say we have two projects:

1. Presentation = The Web-application
2. Definitions = A project
   containing definitions of models

The presentation-project has a dependency to the Definition-project.
The presentation-project has XML-comments enabled, and so does the Definition-project (for all configurations).

The presentation-project has a few comments added to the actions of its controller(s).
The definition-project has a few comments added to the properties of the model(s).

The expected result would be that when I publish the Presentation-project, we should end up with two XML- files in the bin folder:

- Presentation.xml
- Definitions.xml

The names might of course alter if any other name has been specified in the build-properties of each project.
The actual result is that only Presentation.xml is published to the bin-folder.

I have tried to link resulting Definitions.xml-file to the Presentation-project as setting it as "Content" and to always copy, that ended up in the file getting copied to the root-folder of the application during a publish and not the /bin-folder.
I have tried the same thing but linked it into the bin-folder of the Presentation-project, but that ened up with the result of the Definitions.xml-file ending up at /bin/bin/Definitions.xml.
I have tried linking and setting Always, but that did nothing.

Here is a simple sample that can be used to reconstruct the problem:
https://github.com/Inx51/publishdemo

However.. one thing to notice is that the Definitions.xml-file is indeed copied to the /bin-folder during build, but its not copied once using publish.

Anyone that has a workaround for this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your project XML file, `.csproj`/`.vbproj`, and include this in the first `PropertyGroup`:

`<ExcludeXmlAssemblyFiles>false</ExcludeXmlAssemblyFiles>`

This will include all the `.xml` of all dependent assemblies.